Cant login with RDP to remote host after changing MS account password
I recently changed my Microsoft account password which I use for hotmail and to connect to my local PCs. Now when I try to RDP to my Win10 PC I have on my LAN, in no longer accepts my (new) credentials.
Tried connecting a physical monitor, mouse and KB to the Win10 PC, noticed it said there was something wrong with my credentials, elected to fix it, provided my new PW, and it was happy with that.  Rebooted the PC, connected OK with my PIN.
Tried again to remotely access it (from my other PC on the LAN running Win11) and it still won't let me on with the new credentials. ("Credentials did not work. Login attempt failed")
I can login the Win10 box OK with the local KVM.
How do I make the Win10 machine accept my new credentials when connecting with RDP?  Are the old ones cached somewhere?  Help!
